# How to trigger an section update in NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using NSFetchedResultsController to display a list of workouts grouped in sections with the date on which they were completed.

Graphically it can be represented as this:

**JAN 20, 2020**

Workout 1

Workout 2

**JAN 21, 2020**

Workout 1

Workout 2

Each section display's the total distance covered by the user on that day.

Whenever I update any workout (change it's distance) the tableView cell's are updated but the section which contains the total distance for day doesn't change.

I have to reload the tableView to get the changes in effect.

The delegate method in **NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate** : `controller(_:didChange:atSectionIndex:for:)` is only called when a new section is added or removed.

I have searched many SO questions but haven't found any solution. Would be great if any one pointed me in the right direction regarding this.

Below is how I am creating my **NSFetchResultsController**

```
    lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<CD_Run> = {

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<MY_ENTITY>(entityName: "MY_ENTITY")

        let sectionSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "daySectionIdentifier", ascending: false)
        let startTimeSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "startTime", ascending: false)

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sectionSortDescriptor, startTimeSortDescriptor]
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 200

        let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
                                                    managedObjectContext: CoreDataManager.shared()._managedObjectContext,
                                                    sectionNameKeyPath: "daySectionIdentifier",
                                                    cacheName: nil)
        controller.delegate = self
        return controller
    }()
```

Comment: Your code example doesn't show such calculated property so it is hard to help you but my guess is that you won't get any support from NSFetchResultsController for this and that you must fire a re-calculation of that property manually.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I am calculating the section data in the `tableView(:tableView, viewForHeaderInSection section:)` func which just extracts the section data from the  **fetchResultsController** var & sums the distance for that day

Comment: In the FRC delegate methods for object changes, identify which sections the objects belong to, and then use `headerView(forSection:)` to get a reference to the section header view, and update it with the new total.

Comment: I'll try this and update if this approach works for me